# tx_bad_seq error when creating account with the root account of Stellar private network

Tags: go-sdk

I constructed the Stellar private network on my Mac following
https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html#starting-a-new-network
with postgres and horizon server.
I know what the root account and its secret seed of my Stellar node is.

I tried creating a new account with Stellar go SDK. 
From the information of 
https://www.stellar.org/developers/go/reference/examples.html
and https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/friendbot/internal/friendbot.go (Pay method),
I made a simple client for account creation.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/stellar/go/keypair"
    b "github.com/stellar/go/build"
    "github.com/stellar/go/clients/horizon"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    pair, err := keypair.Random()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(pair.Seed())
    log.Println(pair.Address())

    to := pair.Address()

    from := "SDHOAMBNLGCE2MV5ZKIVZAQD3VCLGP53P3OBSBI6UN5L5XZI5TKHFQL4" // root seed at --newdb time

    var PrivateNetClient = &horizon.Client{
        URL:  "http://localhost:8000",
        HTTP: http.DefaultClient,
    }

    tx, err := b.Transaction(
        b.SourceAccount{AddressOrSeed: from},
        b.AutoSequence{SequenceProvider: PrivateNetClient},
        //b.Sequence{Sequence: 1},
        b.TestNetwork,
        b.CreateAccount(
            b.Destination{AddressOrSeed: to},
            b.NativeAmount{Amount: "1000.00"},
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    txe, err := tx.Sign(from)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    txeB64, err := txe.Base64()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("tx base64: %s", txeB64)

    resp, err := PrivateNetClient.SubmitTransaction(txeB64)
    if err != nil {
        switch e := err.(type) {
        case *horizon.Error:
            fmt.Println("err type=" + e.Problem.Type)
            fmt.Println("err detailed=" + e.Problem.Detail)
            fmt.Println("err extras=" + string(e.Problem.Extras["result_codes"]))
        }
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("transaction posted in ledger:", resp.Ledger)
}
```

Making the base64 string of CreateAccount operation XDR is so far so good, but the result of SubmitTransaction is always 400(Bad Request Error) with 'tx_bad_seq'.

stellar-core and horizon are running with debug log level but there's no noticeable log.

How can I resolve this? (The message below is my client log.)

```
2018/02/11 10:38:27 SD7AK2XVUZPVCNTJEKIG5ZZ4CXYXRMMB55YBAMAWCPTI3T3T7WYIBEKN
2018/02/11 10:38:27 GDTD7B3NDD7YEDPPP2MWGTX2K5DXGTDECUYSDWFTVBIMMD7O5SBUFE5M
tx base64: AAAAAGL8HQvQkbK2HA3WVjRrKmjX00fG8sLI7m0ERwJW/AX3AAAAZAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA5j+HbRj/gg3vfpljTvpXR3NMZBUxIdizqFDGD+7sg0IAAAACVAvkAAAAAAAAAAABVvwF9wAAAEA8s/KhXtXz77Q5wu+lj/z/OgLE25CahIJWUB12+9LR6g5BiG/CBB9e143VTUoivu6yF8i8MXRuCyIF2TzCsxYLerr type=https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed
err detailed=The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html
err extras={
      "transaction": "tx_bad_seq"
    }
panic: Horizon error: "Transaction Failed". Check horizon.Error.Problem for more information.

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/eugene/project/ylabs/stellar_client/new_account_with_sdk.go:63 +0xb5e
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to my mind is that your node actually synced with the publicly available test network and applied the history. That's why the master account's (`GBRPYHIL2CI3FNQ4BXLFMNDLFJUNPU2HY3ZMFSHONUCEOASW7QC7OX2H`) sequence number is higher than 1 and you're getting `tx_bad_seq`.

If you want to create a fully isolated network change `network_passphrase` in stellar core configuration and create a new `Network` object in Go SDK with such passphrase.

Comment: It’s the sole node in the private network. Actually it wasn’t the sequence problem, but I think horizon has a problem that it processes other types of error as tx_bad_seq.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to call ‘stellar-core --forcescp’ before running my core node. After the first CreateAccount request is timed out because the node doesn’t process anything, the next requests are failed with ‘tx_bad_seq’ error. So I misunderstood that it was the sequence problem.

I added the issue below.
https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/1540